# Getting index out of range error when trying to remove a list element

Tags: python, list, indexing, range

I have a list such as this:

```
l = ['(7 - 3)', '7 - 6', '(a + 13)']
```

I want to remove any expression that does NOT contain the letter `"a"` therefore the only expression that would be left is `['(a+13)']`. 
So far I have tried this:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    if "a" not in l[i]:
        l.pop(i)
else:
    print(l[i])
```

However I am getting a list index out of range error, and do not know how to fix this.
Could anyone help resolve this?

Comment: When you pop an element from the list you decrease the size of the list while the for loop keeps the old length. I would suggest to use a second list to pop from.

Comment: I would suggest a new approach and create a new list and .append() items that __do__ contain 'a':
    
    new = []
    # you were using 'l' for 'currentlist'
    for i in currentlist:
        if "a" in i:
            new.append(i)

Answer (score 3):

`l.pop()` removes elements from the list, so your list is getting smaller but you are not adjusting your iteration.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x.pop(0)
1
>>> x
[2, 3]
>>> x.pop(1)
3
>>> x
[2]
>>> x.pop(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

I would suggest you take a different approach. You could iterate over the elements of the list directly and print the ones that have `"a"` in them.

```
for i in l:
  if "a" in i:
     print(i)
```

If you need the list to have only the elements that have `"a"` in them at the end of your iteration, perhaps you would like to *add* those items to a new list.

```
things_with_a_in_them = []
for i in l:
  if "a" in i:
    things_with_a_in_them.append(i)
    print(i)
```

If you want it to be terser...

```
things_with_a_in_them = [i for i in l if "a" in i]
map(print, things_with_a_in_them)
```

Have fun playing around with different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Never structurally manipulate a `list` while iterating over it! Use a conditional comprehension

```
l = [x for x in l if 'a' in x]
```

or [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
l = filter(lambda x: 'a' in x, l)
# in Python3, you will have to convert the filter object to a list
# l = list(filter(lambda x: 'a' in x, l))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `len(l)` returns `3`, but as soon as you pop an item, your list becomes shorter. Easiest thing to do (assuming your list isn't prohibitively giant) would be to just write a new list:

```
l_new = [i for i in l if "a" in i]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new `list`, and keep your logic with the `pop`, you would have to check for the `len(l)` everytime, you can do that by:

```
l = ['(7 - 3)', '7 - 6', '(a + 13)']

i = 0
while i < len(l):
    if "a" not in l[i]:
        l.pop(i)
    else:
        print(l[i])
        i += 1
```

But as others have aswered, it would be better to create a new `list` with list comprehension